# disable functions by unset

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

Un my bash script I have many times the function `FuncGenrator`. In order to disable/delete the function I do the following:

```
unset  FuncGenrator
```

`unset` command disabled all function in my script.
The major problem is that when script is running, every function returns the *command not found* error. For example, the script `unset_test.bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

FuncGenrator () {
    echo " I AM REAL FUNCTION BUT NEED TO UNSET LATTER "
}


FuncGenrator
unset FuncGenrator
# run again the function  
FuncGenrator
```

when I run this script I get on the output:

```
I AM REAL FUNCTION BUT NEED TO UNSET LATTER 
./unset_test.bash: line 23: FuncTest: command not found
```

Is it possible to add smart way to block/disable the messages *command not found*, or maybe set the function `FuncGenrator` to no do nothing?

Until now my solution has been to append `2>/dev/null` as follows:

```
FuncGenrator 2>/dev/null
```

but I find it ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of unsetting the function; reset it with a do nothing command:

```
function FuncGenrator { :; }
```

Or

```
FuncGenrator() { :; }
```

Comment: the problem is that I need to add this syntax in the begining of the script , and evry function - FuncGenrator after that will re-write the first one

Comment: @maihabunash Can you add more details how you do it?

Comment: the limitation of adding your syntax --> FuncTest() { :; } , is to add this after my original FuncGenrator () , and not before , if I add it before then my function - FuncGenrator () will overwrite your function and your function not be affective

Comment: I get a feeling there's a better way to do things. Mind posting your actual script? No one really can help if we don't have a clue how things really go.

Comment: ok I vote for you , I think I can manage your solution in my script thx

Answer (score 0):

You can add a test:

test -v FunctionGenerator, where the -v switch checks if the variable is set. Another syntax for this is [ -v FunctionGenerator ].

Example could be :

```
.
.
.
unset FunctionGenerator
if [ -v FunctionGenerator ]; then
    Do something
else
    Do something else
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to consider a flag that, when set, will exit the function right away. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

dont_execute_function=0

FuncGenrator() {
    ((dont_execute_function)) && return
    echo "I AM REAL FUNCTION BUT NEED TO BE UNSET LATTER"
}

FuncGenrator
dont_execute_function=1
FuncGenrator
```

---

Another approach is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

FuncGenrator() {
    echo "I AM REAL FUNCTION BUT NEED TO BE UNSET LATTER"
}
FuncGenrator=FuncGenrator

$FuncGenrator
FuncGenrator=:
$FuncGenrator
```

The trick here is to not call your function directly, but call it via a variable that can be either the name of the function, or the builtin `:` (which is a builtin that does nothing and always returns true).

I'm sure you can find the proper variation on these themes that will suit your needs.